# Stand-alone fabfile for fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Is it possible to make the fabfile stand-alone?
I'm not very fond of running the external tool 'fab'. If I manage to get the fabfile standalone I can run the file from within the (Eclipse / Pydev) IDE, easily debug it, use project configurations and paths etc.
Why doesn't this work:

```
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
    run('uname -s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host_type()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I eventually found the solution (and it is really simple!).
In my fabfile, I added:

```
from fabric.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__, 'update_server']
    main()
```

I hope this helps people...

Comment: Does this spawn a subprocess like muksie's solution? The main reason I was exploring this issue is the extra subprocesses are something we want to eliminate.

Comment: If you alter your sys.argv assignment it'll work with any set of commands. sys.argv[0] is the script name already, so: sys.argv = ['fab', '-f'] + sys.argv

Comment: It's working as long as the file has `.py` extension. I didn't find a way yet to make it work for any extension.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, I couldn't get the Fabric API to do what I wanted either. I decided to abandon the extra layer entirely and use [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) (the underlying SSH library used by Fabric) directly:

```
import os
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname.example.com', 22, 'username', 'password')
ssh.save_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('uname -s')
print stdout.read()
```

While there are a few more steps involved, doing it this way allows you to leverage the SSH layer directly, as opposed to using `subprocess` to spwan another Python instance, or figuring out the Fabric API. I have several projects, both web- and console- using Paramiko in this manner and I haven't had too much trouble.

Paramiko is [extensively documented](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/).

Comment: Sadly, this is the best answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a really nice solution, but will work:

```
import subprocess

def hello():
    print 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', __file__, 'hello'])
```

Comment: Yep, not really nice (but very original +1 !). Also, does not address stdio (e.g. interactive prompt for password (which I assume is solvable)).

Comment: Hijacking the top comment to say that in latest versions of fabric you could use the `execute` command instead of `subprocess.call` http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.3/usage/execution.html#execute .

Answer (score 2):

I fine tuned the above example to past through argv arguments you might want to pass to local commands and specify an optional default_commands list instead of a hard coded command name.  Note, the filename must have a .py extension or fab will not detect it as a fab file!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fabric.api import local

default_commands = ['hello', ]

def hello():
    print ('hello world')

def hostname():
    local('hostname')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import sys
   from fabric.main import main
   sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__,] +  default_commands + sys.argv[1:]
   main()
```

Answer (score 2):

docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/library.html

"As that section mentions, the key is simply that run, sudo and the other
operations only look in one place when connecting: env.host_string . All of
the other mechanisms for setting hosts are interpreted by the fab tool
when it runs, and don’t matter when running as a library."

I was looking at this same problem when I found this. Also, while looking I recall mention that when used in a fabfile, env changes should not be in the same def as run, sudo. Who knows if this still applies when used in "library" mode.

EDIT: Here is an example of said implementation

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def main():
    run("uname -a")

def setup():
    env.host_string = "me@remoteHost"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# thanks to aaron, extending his code a little more
# here is a little bit more of a graceful solution than running subprocess.call, and specifying multiple hosts

from fabric.api import env, run

def main():
    run("uname -a")

def setup():
    env.hosts = ['host0','host1']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    for host in env.hosts:
        env.host_string = host
        main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [1.5.0](http://www.fabfile.org/changelog.html#1.5.0) there is a way better way to do this than messing around with argv.

```
import fabric.main

def main():
    fabric.main.main(fabfile_locations=[__file__])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This can also be utilized as a console script in setup.py

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your fab file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  from fabric.main import main
  import sys

  sys.argv = ['fab', '-f', __file__] + sys.argv[1:]

  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my modified version of [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370048/239247) that changes default behavior to show available commands instead of listing tons of fabric options.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # imports for standalone mode only
    import sys, fabric.main

    # show available commands by default
    if not sys.argv[1:]:
        sys.argv.append('--list')

    fabric.main.main(fabfile_locations=[__file__])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution indirectly on [run fabric file renamed other than fabfile.py and password-less ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994383/run-fabric-file-renamed-other-than-fabfile-py-and-password-less-ssh)

```
def deploy():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from fabric import execute
    execute(deploy)
```

This way also work if your file doesn't have `.py` extension.