# Fabric: call run() for an explicit host

Tags: fabric

I'd like to use fabric as a tool to gather all server loads and process the values afterward, I thought of something like this:

```
from fabric.api import run

for servername in servernames:
    load_str = run('cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1', host=servername)
```

but fabric doesn't allow me to specify the hostname this way, I found this IMO ugly way:

```
from fabric.api import env, run

for servername in servernames:
    env.host_string = servername
    load_str = run('cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1')
```

are there more elegant ways?

Using paramiko directly, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278880/stand-alone-fabfile-for-fabric) pushes me to write an own module that abstracts it - quoting from fabrics website, that's exactly what fabric should do for me:

> In addition to use via the fab fool, Fabric’s components may be imported into other Python code, providing a Pythonic interface to the SSH protocol suite at a higher level than that provided by e.g. Paramiko (which Fabric itself leverages.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question offers a solution:

[How to set target hosts in Fabric file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326797/how-to-set-target-hosts-in-fabric-file)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that fabric really is the wrong tool for that.
The claim quoted above is probably from an earlier version.
Looking at the `run()` code it's clear there's no module in fabric that could be used for my purpose.

There are small abstraction layers around paramiko, e.g. [this one](http://media.commandline.org.uk/code/ssh.txt)

Answer (score 1):

```
from fabric.api import settings

for servername in servernames:
    with settings(host_string=servername):
        load_str = run('cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1')
```

or better using execute

```
from fabric.tasks import execute

data = execute(load_str , hosts = servernames)

def load_str():
    return run('cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1')
```

I'd recommend setting to skip hosts that are not reachable

```
env.skip_bad_hosts = True
```