# executing standalone fabric script by calling it by its name, without the .py extension

Tags: python, fabric

I have a fabric script called `fwp.py` that I run without calling it throug fab by using:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # imports for standalone mode only
    import sys
    import fabric.main

    fabric.main.main(fabfile_locations=[__file__])
```

The thing is then have to call the script by calling `fwp.py`. I'd like to rename it as `fwp` to be able to call it as `fwp`. But doing that would result in

```
Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!
```

Is there a way to make Python/Fabric import this file, despite the lack of a ".py" extension?

To reiterate and clarify:

I'm not using the "fab" utility (e.g. as `fab task task:parameter`); just calling my script as `fwp.py task task:parameter`, and would like to be able to call it as `fwp task task:parameter`.

**Update**

It's not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278880/stand-alone-fabfile-for-fabric). The question is not "How to run a stand-alone fabric script?", but "How to do so, while having a script without a .py" extension.

Comment: should rename it as `fabfile.py`

Comment: No, that's not the issue. I'm running the script as an standalone process, without using running "fab task", just "fwp.py task"; would like it to be "fwp task".

Comment: "fwp.py task" works perfectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stand-alone fabfile for fabric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278880/stand-alone-fabfile-for-fabric)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that at all. I'm already running an stand-alone fabric. My question is if it is possible to have the fabric script file called "script" instead of "script.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Original answer corrected**

The `fabric.main.main()` function automatically adds `.py` to the end of supplied fabfile locations (see https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py#L93).  Unfortunately that function also uses Python's import machinery to load the file so it has to look like a module or package.  Without reimplementing much of the `fabric.main` module I don't think it will be possible.  You could try monkey-patching both `fabric.main.find_fabfiles` and `fabric.main.load_fabfiles` to make it work.

#### Origininal answer (wrong)

I can get this to work unaltered on a freshly installed fabric package.  The following will execute with a filename `fwp` and executable permission on version 1.10.1, Python2.7.  I would just try upgrading fabric.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import *
import fabric.main

def do():
    local('echo "Hello World"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fabric.main.main(fabfile_locations=[__file__])
```

Output:

```
$ ./fwp do
Hello World

Done
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously there is something wrong in my environment, since I have Fabric 1.10.1 and Python 2.7.6. If I run the script as is, it'll work. If instead I use /usr/bin/env python, it'll complain about not finding Fabric. Then again, if I go into the interpreter calling it by "/usr/bin/python", attempts to import fabric.api will fail as well... I guess I'll accept your answer as valid. Syntax is ok, problem is on my end... I'll have to keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is your "fwp" file inside a "package"? (e.g., a dir with `__init__.py` in it?

Comment: Answer corrected.  Sorry, I had left a valid module in the same directory (`fwp.py`) -- it was dumb.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I was going through fabric/main.py and reaching the same conclusion, but since it was working for you I was ready to think there was some python dark magic going on beyond my limited understanding. :P